# Plain parameters slower than creating table parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, table-valued-parameters

I recently discovered the strange behavior, that a function (procedures possibly too) runs significantly slower, when I provide simple NCHAR parameters rather than table value parameters. After trying around a bit I also found, that the function with NCHAR parameters runs as fast as the table value parameter function if I select the NCHAR parameters into a table variable. Here is some code I've created with this.

Function with parameters:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [rpt].[ReportMaterial]
(
            @dateto NCHAR(8),
            @mfrnr NVARCHAR(10),
            @vkorg NVARCHAR(4)
)

RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE 
( 
            MANDT NVARCHAR(3),
            MATNR NVARCHAR(18),
            MFRPN NVARCHAR(40),
            MAKTX NVARCHAR(40),
            WERKS NVARCHAR(4),
            MTART NVARCHAR(4),
            KBETR DECIMAL(11, 2),
            KONWA NVARCHAR(5)
)

AS 

BEGIN

            -- FILL UP
            SELECT @mfrnr = REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(@mfrnr)) + @mfrnr;

            -- OUTPUT
            WITH mat AS
            (
                        -- direct assignment
                        SELECT 
                                   ma.MANDT,
                                   ma.MATNR,
                                   ma.MFRPN,
                                   mc.WERKS,
                                   ma.MTART
                        FROM sap.MARA ma
                        INNER JOIN sap.MARC mc ON ma.MATNR = mc.MATNR AND ma.MANDT = mc.MANDT AND mc.CDCDELETED = 0
                        INNER JOIN
                        (
                                   -- better to use in subselect here
                                   SELECT DISTINCT
                                               WERKS
                                   FROM [sap].[Werks] w
                                   WHERE w.WERKSTYPE = 'D' AND w.VKORG = @vkorg
                        ) w ON w.WERKS = mc.WERKS
                        WHERE ma.MANDT = N'100' AND ma.CDCDELETED = 0 AND ma.MFRNR = @mfrnr
            )

            INSERT INTO @ReturnValue (MANDT, MATNR, MFRPN, MAKTX, WERKS, MTART, KBETR, KONWA)
            SELECT
                        t.MANDT,
                        t.MATNR,
                        t.MFRPN,
                        mk.MAKTX,
                        t.WERKS,
                        t.MTART,
                        COALESCE(pp.KBETR, 0) KBETR,
                        pp.KONWA
            FROM
            (
                        SELECT
                                   m.MANDT,
                                   m.MATNR,
                                   m.MFRPN,
                                   m.WERKS,
                                   m.MTART
                        FROM mat m

                        UNION ALL

                        -- material selection (part of a hardbundle)
                        SELECT 
                                   ma.MANDT,
                                   ma.MATNR,
                                   ma.MFRPN,
                                   ms.WERKS,
                                   ma.MTART
                        FROM sap.MARA ma
                        INNER JOIN sap.MAST ms ON ms.MATNR = ma.MATNR AND ms.STLAN = N'3' AND ms.MANDT = ma.MANDT
                        INNER JOIN sap.STKO ko ON ko.STLNR = ms.STLNR AND ko.STLAL = ms.STLAL AND ko.MANDT = ms.MANDT
                        INNER JOIN sap.STPO po ON po.STLNR = ms.STLNR AND po.MANDT = ms.MANDT
                        INNER JOIN mat mr ON po.IDNRK = mr.MATNR AND mr.MANDT = po.MANDT -- use only relevant items...
                        INNER JOIN
                        (
                                   -- better to use as subselect
                                   SELECT DISTINCT
                                               WERKS
                                   FROM [sap].[Werks] w
                                   WHERE w.WERKSTYPE = 'D' AND w.VKORG = @vkorg
                        ) w ON w.WERKS = ms.WERKS
                        WHERE ma.MTART = N'ZFER' AND ma.MFRNR = N'0080001373'  -- we use only dummy hard bundles (sign for mixed manufacturer bundles)
            ) t
            INNER JOIN sap.MAKT mk ON mk.MATNR = t.MATNR AND mk.SPRAS = N'E' AND mk.MANDT = t.MANDT
            LEFT JOIN sap.PurchasePrice pp ON pp.MATNR = t.MATNR AND pp.WERKS = t.WERKS AND pp.FLIFN = N'X' AND @dateto BETWEEN pp.VDATU AND pp.BDATU AND @dateto BETWEEN pp.DATAB AND pp.DATBI;

            RETURN 

END;
```

Funtion with parameters selected into table variables first:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [rpt].[ReportMaterial]
(
            @dateto NCHAR(8),
            @mfrnr NVARCHAR(10),
            @vkorg NVARCHAR(4)
)

RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE 
( 
            MANDT NVARCHAR(3),
            MATNR NVARCHAR(18),
            MFRPN NVARCHAR(40),
            MAKTX NVARCHAR(40),
            WERKS NVARCHAR(4),
            MTART NVARCHAR(4),
            KBETR DECIMAL(11, 2),
            KONWA NVARCHAR(5)
)

AS 

BEGIN

            -- FILL UP
            SELECT @mfrnr = REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(@mfrnr)) + @mfrnr;

            --> Better performance if using a table to join instead of directly using of parameters

            -- CREATE TABLE
            DECLARE @keyValue TABLE
            (
                        MFRNR NVARCHAR(10),
                        VKORG NVARCHAR(4)
            );

            INSERT INTO @keyValue (MFRNR, VKORG) VALUES (@mfrnr, @vkorg);

            -- OUTPUT
            WITH mat AS
            (
                        -- direct assignment
                        SELECT 
                                   ma.MANDT,
                                   ma.MATNR,
                                   ma.MFRPN,
                                   mc.WERKS,
                                   ma.MTART
                        FROM sap.MARA ma
                        INNER JOIN sap.MARC mc ON ma.MATNR = mc.MATNR AND ma.MANDT = mc.MANDT AND mc.CDCDELETED = 0
                        INNER JOIN
                        (
                                   -- better to use in subselect here
                                   SELECT DISTINCT
                                               WERKS
                                   FROM [sap].[Werks] w
                                   INNER JOIN @keyValue kv1 ON kv1.VKORG = w.VKORG
                                   WHERE w.WERKSTYPE = 'D'
                        ) w ON w.WERKS = mc.WERKS
                        INNER JOIN @keyValue kv2 ON kv2.MFRNR = ma.MFRNR
                        WHERE ma.MANDT = N'100' AND ma.CDCDELETED = 0
            )

            INSERT INTO @ReturnValue (MANDT, MATNR, MFRPN, MAKTX, WERKS, MTART, KBETR, KONWA)
            SELECT
                        t.MANDT,
                        t.MATNR,
                        t.MFRPN,
                        mk.MAKTX,
                        t.WERKS,
                        t.MTART,
                        COALESCE(pp.KBETR, 0) KBETR,
                        pp.KONWA
            FROM
            (
                        SELECT
                                   m.MANDT,
                                   m.MATNR,
                                   m.MFRPN,
                                   m.WERKS,
                                   m.MTART
                        FROM mat m

                        UNION ALL

                        -- material selection (part of a hardbundle)
                        SELECT 
                                   ma.MANDT,
                                   ma.MATNR,
                                   ma.MFRPN,
                                   ms.WERKS,
                                   ma.MTART
                        FROM sap.MARA ma
                        INNER JOIN sap.MAST ms ON ms.MATNR = ma.MATNR AND ms.STLAN = N'3' AND ms.MANDT = ma.MANDT
                        INNER JOIN sap.STKO ko ON ko.STLNR = ms.STLNR AND ko.STLAL = ms.STLAL AND ko.MANDT = ms.MANDT
                        INNER JOIN sap.STPO po ON po.STLNR = ms.STLNR AND po.MANDT = ms.MANDT
                        INNER JOIN mat mr ON po.IDNRK = mr.MATNR AND mr.MANDT = po.MANDT -- use only relevant items...
                        INNER JOIN
                        (
                                   -- better to use as subselect
                                   SELECT DISTINCT
                                               WERKS
                                   FROM [sap].[Werks] w
                                   INNER JOIN @keyValue kv1 ON kv1.VKORG = w.VKORG
                                   WHERE w.WERKSTYPE = 'D'
                        ) w ON w.WERKS = ms.WERKS
                        WHERE ma.MTART = N'ZFER' AND ma.MFRNR = N'00000000'
            ) t
            INNER JOIN sap.MAKT mk ON mk.MATNR = t.MATNR AND mk.SPRAS = N'E' AND mk.MANDT = t.MANDT
            LEFT JOIN sap.PurchasePrice pp ON pp.MATNR = t.MATNR AND pp.WERKS = t.WERKS AND pp.FLIFN = N'X' AND @dateto BETWEEN pp.VDATU AND pp.BDATU AND @dateto BETWEEN pp.DATAB AND pp.DATBI;

            RETURN  

END;
```

Does anybody have an Idea, why this is the case? Do I need to leverage this effect by allways selecting parameters into temporary tables/table variables?

Comment: I'd advice you to check the execution plans/statistics to see the differences in your situation. I'd be *very* careful taking your experience in this situations and using it as "all cases", because when it comes to temporary tables, table variables and common table expressions there are many factors and therefore situations can quickly weigh into one or the other case.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't see the excecution plan for functions